# Problems with installing python package lmfit under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python

I want to run a python script with ipython, where I need to import the lmfit package. At work I have a windows computer and everything worked there. But my private computer has ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot even install the lmfit package. I have both python 3.4.3 and python 2.7.6 installed. I tried with pip

`pip3 install lmfit`

and what I get is:

```
    Downloading/unpacking lmfit
  Downloading lmfit-0.9.5-py3-none-any.whl (102kB): 102kB downloaded
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from lmfit)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from lmfit)
Installing collected packages: lmfit
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/lmfit'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/kristin/.pip/pip.log
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-lmfit
```

With that it tells me that lmfit can not be found.

I am really not an expert with those installing problems..I was very happy when I installed python and everything worked. So please excuse me for this maybe stupid question.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pip command has not right to write dirs in `/usr/local/`

So you should try `sudo pip3 install lmfit`

If your ipython is installed under py2, try `sudo pip2 install lmfit`

Comment: and I feel a little bit ashamed. But ok, thank you very much!

Comment: It's OK. by the way, could your upvote my answer and accept it as your correct answer ? thank you ~ @Tini

Answer (score 0):

By typing `sudo pip3 install lmfit`, if your terminal said `from pip import main [...] ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`, the problem can be resolved by a fresh installation of pip3 with `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall` as mentionned here's [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5447)